# How to show an image while my files (most images) are loading?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, loading

I'm making an app with a webview loading my html page. It has a lot of images, and i need to load it all when the app starts.

Is there any way to show an image, while my HTML file is loading all the images?

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just add an `UIImageView` to your view, put it in the foreground, display your image in there, and when your web view finishes loading (in the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate), blend out the `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

//set an image in your imageView and remove it from hidden, set webview hidden

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

// load your html page code here

}

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

//set your imageview to hidden and display your webview.

});
});